# Дополнительный header элемент непонятно откуда

Tags: html, css, sass

По какой-то причине на странице появляется дополнительный `header` элемент непонятно откуда

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Museum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="preload">
    <div class="loading-center">
        <div class="loading-center-absolute">
            <div class="object object_one"></div>
            <div class="object object_two"></div>
            <div class="object object_three"></div>
            <div class="object object_four"></div>
            <div class="object object_five"></div>
            <div class="object object_six"></div>
            <div class="object object_seven"></div>
            <div class="object object_eight"></div>
            <div class="object object_nine"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<main class="main__wrapper">
    <header>
        <div class="header__logo">
            <img src="img/additional/main_logo.png" alt="logotype">
        </div>
        <div class="header__right-info">
            <img src="img/additional/search_ico.png" alt="search_icon">
            <img src="img/additional/profile_ico.png" alt="profile_icon">
            <ul>
                <li>Eng</li>
                <li>О проекте</li>
                <li>На сайт музея</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <header>
</main>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

В коде всего один такой эелемент. А все браузеры добавляют второй
Хотя там вместо этого ul элемент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили:

```css
@import: '_fonts.sass';
@import: '_settings.sass';
@import: '_variables.sass';

.main__wrapper
 width: 100%
 display: flex
 justify-content: center

//header

header
 display: flex
 justify-content: space-between
```

Answer (score 7):

Судя по коду, который вы оставили, Вы не закрыли тег `<header>` (у Вас в коде их два).

```
<main class="main__wrapper">
    <header>

        ...

    <header>
</main>
```

Comment: Очень простая ошибка, извиняюсь :( И такое бывает